# Time ago pipe using Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set time-ago-pipe in my application, I tried this example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-ago-pipe

But it works just with AngularJS, I'm using 4.

this is the error when I put TimeAgoPipe in declaration:

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ./time-ago-pipe;
```

app.modules

```
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [.......]
.
.
.

 declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TimeAgoPipe
    ],
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "time-ago-pipe":"^1.2.1"
```

time.component.html

```
  <div class="author-date">
      <div class="post__date">
         <time class="timeago" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">
            {{info.time | timeAgo }}
         </time>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Note: my info.time in console is (1514112341)

Comment: It would help if you showed your package.json, and app.module.ts (or whatever you use to import modules

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: Now it worked but it is always 48 years ago

Comment: Originally you were facing integration issue, which is why helpers here would need to look at package.json, and app.module.ts, now it sounds like potentially an error in code. Can you show code with usage of it?

Comment: Please check now, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts, make sure you're declaring a Date type

i.e.

```
  info.time = new Date("2004-07-24T18:18");
```

Also you shouldn't need to use  tag

```
<span>{{info.time | timeAgo}}</span>
```

As for the 48 years ago issue, there seems to be a conversion issue between the date you're using

if you debug this further

```
your_date  = new Date("2004-07-24T18:18");
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.your_date);
    console.log(new Date(1514112341));
  }
```

you can see how the two don't match

[image]

Notice how the pure number format is parsed as 1970. So the real issue is in the format you're supplying timeAgo. It needs it in a Date() type because it is

> parsed by the standard Js Date()

Comment: If I already have (1514112341) coming from API, why should I declaring a Date type?

Comment: Where are you defining info.time?

Comment: All the data that coming from API stored in data[], so in my html I used  <div *ngFor="let info of data"> , then I can reach any data I want by using (info.something), I told you in my console the time is correct, I just want to convert from (1514112341) to (about a minute ago) for example, but it is always (48 years ago).

Comment: How are you printing 1514112341 to console, and what api?

Comment: so now in my ts component I just need to do this:     timeAgo = new Date();
? because it is pipe I don't know where can I find it to parse by the standard js Date()

Comment: timeAgo pipe is compatible with Date(), which is part of typescript so you dont have to worry about importing anything. Can you answer the question, how are you printing 1514112341, and/or what API supplies it?

Comment: I solved it by replacin {{info.time | timeAgo }} to {{info.time * 1000 | timeAgo }} thank you dear